# Postgresql 11 row insert low performance using jdbc

Tags: postgresql, database-performance, postgresql-11

I am trying to improve the performance of row insertion in a postgresql 11 db using standard java prepared statements.
It is standing on top of debian 11 in a VM environnement.
I am using pentaho data integration and a simple table output step.
I want to make my transformation database transactional so using batch update is not an option.
I have created tables without index, nor constraints and made then unlogged. They have a few columns.
I am currently getting row insert top speed of 40 r/s per connection.
I can increase this speed by using parallelism and each connection tends to reach this speed.

The server is running smoothly using 3% cpu and about 10% RAM.

How can I increase the "per connection" row insert performance ?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Do you run the inserts in a single transaction? What kind of storage do you have, and how is it attached? How many indexes and constraints are on the table? Triggers? Can we see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` outputfor such an insert?

Comment: "I want to make my transformation database transactional so using batch update is not an option."   Why not?  Batch updates also execute inside transactions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
I do not know how to get the explain from pdi.
I am filling a table with no constraints (no not null, no index, no primary key, no external key), so I was thinking the plan was not the issue.

Comment: @jjanes, pdi is not allowing it. When you set the transactional option, each connection spec becomes unique and batch updates are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are bottlenecked by synchronous write speed.  That makes the solution easy.  Buy storage hardware that supports faster fsync speed and put your pg_wal directory on that storage.

Comment: I have launched ioping commande, but I am not able to read the results:
`--- . (ext4 /dev/sda1) ioping statistics ---
9 requests completed in 3.92 ms, 72 KiB written, 2.29 k iops, 17.9 MiB/s
generated 10 requests in 9.00 s, 80 KiB, 1 iops, 8.89 KiB/s
min/avg/max/mdev = 379.0 us / 435.6 us / 551.3 us / 48.6 us`

Comment: Try running `pg_test_fsync` on the disk and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it came from my connection to the server.
I was using a ssh tunnel (I should have stated it, sorry).
Using a direct connection, I get decent insert times.
I did not suspect it as I was having good performance using batches.

Thanks for your answers